# Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'void *' to '__unsafe_unretained id *' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to migrate to ARC but I get this error, i really don't know how to resolve this one :

```
    NSArray *itemsArray = nil;

    __unsafe_unretained id *objArray = calloc (itemRange.length, sizeof (id)); //got the error here
    [fdEntries getObjects:objArray range:itemRange]; //fdEntries is an NSMutableArray
    itemsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:objArray count:itemRange.length];
    free(objArray);
```

Here is the error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'void *' to '__unsafe_unretained id *' is disallowed with ARC.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What are you trying to do - are you trying to not use `alloc` for an array of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be replaced by a solution without manual memory management:

```
 NSArray *itemsArray = [fdEntries subarrayWithRange:itemRange];
```

Comment: ok I will try the solution and i'll let you know if it's working asap... thanks